# WinDbg: Regarding output of dt command

Tags: windbg

When I dump the details of a local variable using the dt command in WinDbg i get the following output:

```
0:000> dt uid_out
Local var @ 0x84ebbac Type CString*
0x084ebbfc 
   +0x000 m_pchData        : 0x082f2988  -> 0x31
```

My query is what does `-> 0x31` in the final line specify? Does it specifies the size of the CString?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the value of the first element of the array pointed to by a pointer type.  Since m_pchData is a pointer to CHAR, the debugger shows you the first CHAR value at address 0x82f2988.

Answer (score 1):

> My query is what does -> 0x31 in the final line specify? Does it
>   specifies the size of the CString?

It's not being that smart, I suspect it's just the first byte of the pointer contents. You can confirm with:

```
dc 0x082f2988
```